# Why does DateInterval lack weeks, quarters/seasons, as well as decimal/float versions of each property?

Tags: php, time

This has puzzled and frustrated me for years: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

```
y

    Number of years.
m

    Number of months.
d

    Number of days.
h

    Number of hours.
i

    Number of minutes.
s

    Number of seconds.
f

    Number of microseconds, as a fraction of a second.
```

Where are the weeks and quarters/seasons? In particular, the weeks are sorely missing. In turn, I feel as if *I* am missing something.

You'd call me crazy if you knew how many hours of my life I've plowed into trying to manually calculate the weeks and seasons and decimal versions of all of these based on the existing values, without luck.

I don't want "rough approximations", because they fall apart as the two dates drift too far away from each other. "Rough approximations" are easy to make, but I'm looking for exact, accurate information.

Comment: Weeks, in the sense of any 7 day period, are catered to as an interval of 7 days. Quarters, in the sense of any 3 month period, are catered to as an interval of 3 months.

Comment: "Features start out nonexistent and somebody has to make them happen." -- Raymond Chen.

Answer (score 2):

How would you describe a quarter, if not as a 3 month period?
How would you describe a week, if not as as 7 day period?

There are no custom interval created for an arbitrary amount of intervals that already exist. If you want to jump ahead a quarter, add 3 months. If you want to go back a week, subtract 7 days.

I'm using C# here, but I expect the syntax is readable enough:

```
var oneWeekAgo =        DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
var oneQuarterFurther = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
```

> how many hours of my life I've plowed into trying to manually calculate the weeks and seasons

- Weeks: count the difference in days, divide by 7. Use rounding the way you see fit.
- Quarters: count the difference in months, divide by 3. Use rounding the way you see fit.

If a simple division takes you hours upon hours, you've got bigger problems than the absence of some arbitrary premade intervals.

> I'm looking for exact, accurate information.

See the above explanation of how to use division. The information will be as accurate as the language allows division to be, which is usually much more accurate than datekeeping generally requires.

> Where are the weeks and quarters/**seasons**?

Not everyone agrees on where a season starts and ends.

I've got real life experience here. My partner is from a different culture than me. She considers the seasons to align with each quarter (Jan 1, Apr 1, Jul 1, Oct 1), but in my culture, the dates are closer to the meteorological season shifts (Dec 21, Mar 21, Jun 21, Sep 21). One of our mutual friends is from another culture, and they shift by one month compared to my partner (Dec 1, Mar 1, Jun 1, Sep 1)

This is no different from the argument on whether the week starts on Saturday/Sunday/Monday. Everyone has their own preference, and that preference does matter when calculating the amount of calendar weeks' difference between two dates; but since there's no universal standard, it's impossible to create a reasonable premade standard for it. Such a standard would be unusable for anyone who thinks the week starts on a different day than the standard defines it as.

---

To summarize, you're asking for more intervals, but the intervals you're interested in are already trivially expressed using the existing intervals. Just use the existing intervals.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that all intervals that `DateInterval` stores, with the exception of `$days`, are additive. i.e. 13 months difference will _generally_ show up as `y = 1; m = 1;`. Adding a `$weeks` counter would accomplish nothing, but would only make it that much harder to use. Why would you prefer "1 month, 2 weeks, 2 days" over "1 month, 16 days" as your default?

Comment: @Duroth: I think there can be contextual reason to favor "1 month, 2 weeks, 2 days" (or, maybe more commonly seen online: "posted 2 weeks ago"), but the point is more that the triviality of calculating 16d = 2w2d effectively negates the need for creating preset week intervals.

Comment: You're right; my comment was slightly unclear. Calculating the weeks is trivial; removing the weeks and calculating days also is, but depending on your use case, you'll need to do one or the other.